# How to get poopover on list item in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to get tooltip or poopover like menu on list item

i have a simple list item like this

```
       items: [
            {  icon: 'mdi-dots-horizontal' },
            {  icon: 'mdi-format-italic' },
        ]
```

it is constructed like this in vue

```
        <v-list
                nav
                dense
              >
                <v-list-item-group
                  v-model="selectedItem"
                  color="primary"
                >
                  <v-list-item
                    v-for="(item, i) in items"
                    :key="i"
                  >
                    <v-list-item-icon>
                      <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-icon>

                  </v-list-item>
                </v-list-item-group>
              </v-list>
```

for **2nd** list item i want my result like shown below in the image

[image]

how to achieve like that in vuetify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too complicated and you only need to wrap your layout inside the `<v-menu>`

```
 <v-menu v-model="menu" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-width="200">
     <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          color="indigo"
          dark
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on">
            Menu as Popover
        </v-btn>
      </template>
     <v-card>
         <v-list nav dense>
             <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedItem" color="primary">
                 <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
                     <v-list-item-icon>
                         <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
                     </v-list-item-icon>
                  </v-list-item>
              </v-list-item-group>
          </v-list>
      </v-card>
  </v-menu>
```

For the script:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        menu: false,
        items: [{  icon: 'mdi-dots-horizontal' },
                {  icon: 'mdi-format-italic'   }]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

To see the full tutorial click [Here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#accessibility)